# Android In app purchase: This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

When I try to run my application with in-app billing I am getting the error: "This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play. Check the help center for more information".

I have the billing permission already in the Manifest file and I have a signed .apk uploaded as a draft onto Google Play and I have also installed that same signed apk onto my phone as well as i also provided productId,and already waited for more than a day for their server to upload but still getting error.

Answer (score 1):

I ran to this issue a lot. I would suggest using this link

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment-v3/

keep the product ID as **android.test.purchased**. (Change your Base64 if you want to) set up all of your code and get you app sorted, response handling and everything else.

Then put the app in the Google Play dont publish it (Check your version number, and keep the certificate). Add your Products (As you have already done.)

I do the following then: 
In Eclipse export your app with the same Certificate and version number as the one you have on the store. put it in a different folder.

Use these commands to uninstall the app from the test phone and install it:

```
adb uninstall com.domain.appname
```

and install it with this:

```
adb -d install /path/to/new/apk
```

Then run the app on the test phone.

Your test phone has to be setup with the test Google Account. if not you need to reset the phone and set it up with the test account.

If your logCat is open you should see all the logs also your app should go through with no issue.

Please let me know how you go so I can help you further.

One more thing. I set up a Google Community for my testers and add the test accounts in there so I can test on multiple devices easily. Also you can add the test account in the setting of your GooglePlay. There are lots of document for this too.

H.